# What is the British meaning of the word, "bloody?"

Tags: meaning

What does bloody mean in the British language?  I hear it used all the time but I do not know the meaning of the word, "bloody."

Comment: It's just a general-purpose obscenity.

Comment: And, of course, it can be used in its literal meaning, as when Shakespeare's King Duncan sees a wounded soldier and asks 'What bloody man is that?'

Answer (score 2):

A rather lengthy etymology of bloody:  [Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bloody#etymonline_v_13621)

**bloody** (adj.)

> It has been a British intensive swear word at least since 1676.
>   Weekley relates it to the purely intensive use of the cognate Dutch
>   bloed, German Blut. But perhaps it ultimately is connected with bloods
>   in the slang sense of "rowdy young aristocrats" (see blood (n.)) via
>   expressions such as bloody drunk "as drunk as a blood."
>
> Partridge reports that it was "respectable" before c. 1750, and it was
>   used by Fielding and Swift, but heavily tabooed c. 1750-c. 1920,
>   perhaps from imagined association with menstruation; Johnson calls it
>   "very vulgar," and OED writes of it, "now constantly in the mouths of
>   the lowest classes, but by respectable people considered 'a horrid
>   word', on par with obscene or profane language."
>
> The onset of the taboo against bloody coincides with the increase in linguistic prudery that presaged the Victorian Era but it is hard
>   to say what the precise cause was in the case of this specific word.
>   Attempts have been made to explain the term's extraordinary shock
>   power by invoking etymology. Theories that derive it from such oaths
>   as "By our Lady" or "God's blood" seem farfetched, however. More
>   likely, the taboo stemmed from the fear that many people have of blood
>   and, in the minds of some, from an association with menstrual
>   bleeding. Whatever, the term was debarred from polite society during
>   the whole of the nineteenth century. [Rawson]
>
> Shaw shocked theatergoers when he put it in the mouth of Eliza
>   Doolittle in "Pygmalion" (1914), and for a time the word was known
>   euphemistically as "the Shavian adjective." It was avoided in print as
>   late as 1936. Bloody Sunday, Jan. 30, 1972, was when 13 civilians were
>   killed by British troops at protest in Londonderry, Northern Ireland.

Following the original use in England, Scotland, and Ireland, the sense spread to most other parts of the English-speaking world, with the notable exception of the United States, where it has apparently only ever achieved limited currency, e.g. among sailors during the 19th cent.

The figurative meaning of **bloody** from the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20448?rskey=syth8v&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> an intensifier: absolute, downright, utter. Formerly sometimes in a
>   negative sense: awful, terrible. More recently also as a mere filler,
>   with little or no intensifying force (although generally implying some
>   element of dislike, frustration, etc., on the part of the speaker).

Comment: Um... I don't know if it has waned in popularity in recent years, but in the New England States - up until at least the 80's - "bloody" was an oft-used expletive. ("Bleedin'" however, stayed on it's own side of the pond.)